# Retorno de tipos dynamic WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou escrevendo um metodo em WebApi que retorna o tipo **HttpResponseMessage**.

Tenho uma consulta que retorna um tipo **dynamic** que iria retornar a consulta dos dados pois são informações diferentes.

No retorno dos dados acaba por ocorrer um erro mas o Visual Studio reclamou de problemas no código. Porém notei algo curioso

Mensagem de erro no Visual Studio

> Error CS1973  'HttpRequestMessage' has no applicable method named
>   'CreateResponse' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

Se eu coloco o código no seguinte formato:

Permitido

```
var retorno = new { cupons =  Api.Consultar(codigo) };
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
```

Não permitido

```
var retorno = Api.Consultar(codigo);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
```

Assuma que Api.Consultar() retorna um objeto do tipo *dynamic*

Qual a diferença entre estes dois códigos onde um é aceito e outro não?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "Não permitido"? Há um erro de compilação? Há um erro de execução? Qual o erro? Qual a assinatura do método Api.Consultar?

Comment: Oi @GabrielFerrarini realmente fiquei devendo a mensagem de erro, complementei no texto. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A assinatura do método [Request.CreateResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969057(v=vs.118).aspx) utiliza [Generic Type Parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) que não permite, por design, a passagem de um `dynamic` (variável não tipada), ou seja o compilador não sabe o seu tipo (classe) durante a compilação, somente em tempo de execução.

Porém o parâmetro genérico permite o uso de [Anonymous Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) que são, como o nome diz, tipos (classes) sem nome com os seus "nomes" conhecidos apenas pelo compilador durante a compilação.

No primeiro trecho, a variável é inicializada via sintaxe de inicialização de objetos anônimos, sendo então um objeto filho de uma classe "sem nome" conhecido apenas pelo compilador ao compilar. E se é um objeto então é aceito como argumento pelo `Generic Type Parameter`.

```
var retorno = new { cupons =  Api.Consultar(codigo) };
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
```

No segundo trecho, a variável do tipo `var` ([Implicit typed local variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables)) recebe um `dynamic`, o que seria o mesmo que ter declarado a variável como sendo `dynamic`. Ao compilar, acontece o erro pois um parâmetro `Generic Type Parameter` não aceita uma variável `dynamic` como argumento, por definição. Uma solução seria fazer um cast da variável "retorno", como sugerido pelo compilador.

```
var retorno = Api.Consultar(codigo);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, retorno);
```